# Cannot write custom dictionaries to YAML

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I have working python code that makes use of three nested classes:

```py
@dataclass
class PanelGroup:
    num_panels: int
    panel_efficiency: float
    panel_surface: float
    elevation: int


class PanelString(dict[str, PanelGroup]):
    pass


class SolarInstallation(dict[str, PanelString]):
    pass
```

The way I create instances of these classes, statically, from my code is:

```py
solar_installation = SolarInstallation(
        SSW_12=PanelString(G1=PanelGroup(4, 0.191, 1.705, 50),
                           G2=PanelGroup(5, 0.191, 1.705, 50)))
```

I want to make this configuration come from a YAML file, so I trying to get to work the following snippet of code to dump the correct YAML contents to a file:

```py
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.register_class(SolarInstallation)
yaml.register_class(PanelString)
yaml.register_class(PanelGroup)
yaml.dump(solar_installation, sys.stdout)
```

But the only thing I get is an empty dictionary:

```py
!SolarInstallation {}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to tell `ruamel.yaml` how to dump your classes, just registering is not
enough:

```py
import sys
from dataclasses import dataclass
import ruamel.yaml


@dataclass
class PanelGroup:
    num_panels: int
    panel_efficiency: float
    panel_surface: float
    elevation: int

    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        d = {}
        for k in node.__annotations__:
            d[k] = node.__getattribute__(k)
        return representer.represent_mapping('!' + cls.__name__, d)

class PanelString(dict[str, PanelGroup]):
    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_mapping('!' + cls.__name__, node)


class SolarInstallation(dict[str, PanelString]):
    @classmethod
    def to_yaml(cls, representer, node):
        return representer.represent_mapping('!' + cls.__name__, node)

solar_installation = SolarInstallation(
        SSW_12=PanelString(G1=PanelGroup(4, 0.191, 1.705, 50),
                           G2=PanelGroup(5, 0.191, 1.705, 50)))
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.register_class(SolarInstallation)
yaml.register_class(PanelString)
yaml.register_class(PanelGroup)
yaml.dump(solar_installation, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
!SolarInstallation
SSW_12: !PanelString
  G1: !PanelGroup
    num_panels: 4
    panel_efficiency: 0.191
    panel_surface: 1.705
    elevation: 50
  G2: !PanelGroup
    num_panels: 5
    panel_efficiency: 0.191
    panel_surface: 1.705
    elevation: 50
```

Comment: I realise after answering that subclasses of dict (like `PanelString` and `SolarInstallation` could be automatically dumped (with tag), with a small code change in ruamel.yaml. I'll try to remember that for a future update. When you want to load this back, you need to define `from_yaml` class_methods.